# VBScript to move windows around

Tags: windows, vba, vbscript

Is it possible to move windows only using VBScript ? I have two monitors on my computer and I want to make a script that opens two applications: one on each monitor. I was thinking of using SendKeys Windows Key + Left, but that seems difficult to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are three ways that I'm aware of for this, listed in order of preference.

1. If you create the application via something like `CreateObject("myApp")` and your application has methods for moving it directly, you can use those.
2. [Use DynaCall](http://www.borncity.com/web/WSHBazaar1/WSHDynaCall.htm) which should allow you to declare the relevant system dlls to use the API to move the windows. This page has a [long explanation on how this might be accomplished](http://www.microsoftfaqs.com/msg/1677124.aspx). 
   Note: that DynaCall is not necessary if you are actually using VBA, mentioned only because you put VBA as a tag.
3. Use `SendKeys` like you suggested.

Comment: I could use that method 1, which proved easier indeed